# How to build python application to linux executable one file？

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, pyinstaller, centos7

I want to compile a python script (GUI application written by pyqt5) into a single exe file. I have successfully done it on window with pyinstaller. However, when I tried the same thing on Linux(CentOS7), it turned out to be a "shared library" items. I could still run the file from terminal but I want to get an applicaiton that can be opened by simply double-click.

Comment: I think with Linux you don't need an executable really, just a shebang at the top of the file, rename it without the .py extension and make it executable i.e. add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top, rename to `main` instead of `main.py`, then do `chmod 755 main`

Comment: @RolvApneseth Thanks very much for the suggestion. I think your idea would be more appropriate for a single python script. As we wanted to make our scripts more transferrable so we want to make it into a single application file. Do you mean I can added  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` into the shared library file I mentioned above?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't read through properly. I'm not sure how hard it is but have you looked at maybe making an AppImage? Sorry I can't help more, upvoted your question so hopefully someone with more experience can hopefully have a look at it.

Comment: @RolvApneseth Thanks very much for the help and really appreciate the upvote.